# Where can I find free Ruby and Python logos for a commercial site?

Tags: python, ruby, open-source, graphical-logo

I need a Ruby and Python logo, usable free of charge for a commercial site.

On Google Images, I have not been able to find such logos; All of them have no clearly specified license.

Where can I find such "free" logos?

Comment: another case of "google makes you stupid"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Python logos](http://www.python.org/community/logos/)

[Ruby logos](http://rubyidentity.org/)

As long as you follow the (fairly liberal) usage guidelines/license, there is no issue with you using them.

Comment: What happened to 'what have you tried so far?' ;-) . And this information was easily available by just using Google.

Comment: @A: Well, he said he tried Google Images. That would not have been my (or many people's truth be told) first choice, but...

Answer (score 3):

The rules regarding the Python trademark are described here: http://www.python.org/psf/trademarks/ .

Especially:

> Uses that Never Require Approval
>
> All trademarks are subject to "nominative use rules" that allow use of the trademark to name the trademarked entity in a way that is minimal and does not imply a sponsorship relationship with the trademark holder.
>
> As such, stating accurately that software is written in the Python programming language, that it is compatible with the Python programming language, or that it contains the Python programming language, is always allowed. In those cases, you may use the word "Python" or the unaltered logos to indicate this, without our prior approval. This is true both for non-commercial and commercial uses.
>
> This clause overrides other clauses of this policy. However, if you have any doubts about your intended use of the trademarks, please contact the PSF.